# How do I marshal a JAXB object to XOM?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xom

I'm trying to figure out what bits I need to plug together to marshal a JAXB POJO to a XOM document, and vice versa.

The JAXB `Marshaller` interface's marshal methods take various targets, such as `Result`, but none of them have a XOM adapter. Irritatingly, the XOM API does have a `XOMResult` implementation, but it's package protected, and only used internally.

Is there some other way I can marshal to/from XOM without resorting to String or byte buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are adverse to using DOM to accomplish this, as you're probably using XOM to avoid DOM! Anyway, using a JAXB Binder as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347534/jaxb-add-xml-comments-into-marshalled-file/1349275#1349275) along with XOM's [DOMConverter](http://xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/converters/DOMConverter.html), you can go from JAXB to DOM to XOM without using a String or a byte buffer.

It is too bad that XOM doesn't have a utility to create a XOM Document from a SAX ContentHandler, since JAXB also supports marshalling to an instance of that object. XOM has a [SAXConverter](http://xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/converters/SAXConverter.html) that can create a ContentHandler from a Document, but not the other way around.

Here's a thread that relates to this on the [XOM-interest](http://markmail.org/search/?q=xom%20builder%20contenthandler#query:xom%20builder%20contenthandler+page:1+mid:6wqhz6e2jydh3pij+state:results) mailing list.

Comment: Yeah, going from JAXB->DOM->XOM is what I'm currently stuck with, but it leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: I understand completely. Perhaps this is an opportunity to create a contribution to XOM by creating the missing converter? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found old project [nux](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux/):

a http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux//api/nux/xom/pool/XOMUtil.html

jaxbMarshal/jaxbUnmarshal use DOMConverter ;-(

b. http://acs.lbl.gov/software/nux/api/nux/xom/io/StaxUtil.html
...also includes a XOM Builder implementation that uses a StAX parser instead of a SAX parser; plus a XMLStreamReader implementation reading from an underlying XOM Document or fragment; plus other tools.

StaxUtil.createXMLStreamReader(Node root)
          Constructs and returns a StAX XMLStreamReader pull parser implementation that reads from an underlying XOM Node; typically a Document or fragment (subtree); Ideal for efficient conversion of a XOM tree to SOAP/AXIOM, JAXB 2, JiBX or XMLBeans, for example when incrementally converting XQuery results via an Unmarshaller, perhaps in combination with a StreamingPathFilter.

May be this can help?