# Which JAXB implementation implements Marshaller.getNode()?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, marshalling

I am trying to [add a comment](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/java-jsp-35/how-add-comments-jaxb-662301.html) to a JAXB generated XML @GET result, which doesn't seem to be a straight forward task.  I'm using Spring, and [I don't have direct access to the marshalling and DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347534/jaxb-add-xml-comments-into-marshalled-file).

By adding [public void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.Listener.html#beforeMarshal%28java.lang.Object%29) to my @XmlElement, I should be able to access the DOM with [Marshaller#getNode(Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#getNode%28java.lang.Object%29), and thus be able to add a comment.

The problem is [AbstractMarshallerImpl#getNode(Object)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.xml.bind/com.springsource.javax.xml.bind/2.0.0/javax/xml/bind/helpers/AbstractMarshallerImpl.java#AbstractMarshallerImpl.getNode%28java.lang.Object%29):

> By default, the getNode method is
>   unsupported and throw an
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
>   Implementations that choose to support
>   this method must override this method.

Is getNode(Object) implemented by any JAXB implementations out there?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I lead [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and am a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

---

MOXy does not currently support the optional [`getNode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#getNode%28java.lang.Object%29) method see (enhancement request https://bugs.eclipse.org/332762).  However, JAXB's [`Binder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html) may be helpful with this use case:

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.Binder;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Comment;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Jane Doe");

        PhoneNumber homePhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(homePhoneNumber);

        PhoneNumber workPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
        customer.getPhoneNumbers().add(workPhoneNumber);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        binder.marshal(customer, document);
        Node homePhoneNumberElement = binder.getXMLNode(homePhoneNumber);
        Comment comment = document.createComment("My Comment");
        homePhoneNumberElement.appendChild(comment);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        t.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```

**Customer**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
public class PhoneNumber {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Blaise!  The problem is, I don't use the JAXBContext directly.  I just annotate my method with @GET and return a Response.ok(entity).build().

Comment: @neu242 - You could leverage the JAX-RS concept of MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter for this use case.  For an example of how it can be used with JAXB see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388

Comment: OK, I have a @Path("/myApi") @Component @Scope("request") @Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public class MyResource, with a method @GET public Response myMethod() { MyEntity entity = getEntity(); return Response.ok(entity).build();}.  Now, I created an additional @Provider @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"}) public class ValidatingReader implements MessageBodyReader<MyEntity> { ... } like in your example.  The MessageBodyReader doesn't seem to be triggered, what am I missing?