# How to add documentation/comments to XML instance generated from a schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XML schema based on which documents are generated on fly and distributed to third parties.
Is there any way to add comments/documentation to elements in each XML instance generated ?

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you describe the way you generate your schema on the fly.

Comment: Schema is not generated on fly, just the documents complying to the schema generated on fly.

Comment: Ok, don't tell us anything else, let us telepathically guess how you generate your XML instances.

Comment: Using JAXB to generate classes from XMLSchema,which is done offline. Based on these generated classes, XML instance documents are generated during runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347534/add-xml-comments-into-marshaled-file